# Javascript: I placed list of elements in a for loop to perform a certain action on mouseover but only one element is affected

Tags: javascript

I apologize if the answer is too obvious but I just can't get it, I have a navbar on my website with the following code:

```
<div class="navblock"><a href="#">カ</a></div>
<div class="navblock" id="animeblock"><a class="navtext" href="#">ANIME</a></div>
<div class="navblock" id="signinblock"><a class="navtext" href="#">Sign In</a></div>
```

The parent 'navblock' div elements just wrap around the text and change color on 'mouseover' action, like the bootstrap thing but I don't want to use bootstrap because I'm learning. The code I wrote before is just too big and messy and it's just a pain to look at it, this is my new code but the problems with this is that it only affects the 'Sign In' block:

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('navtext')

for(var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++){
    var parentBlock = texts[i].parentElement
    texts[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){parentBlock.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(46,46,46,0.5)'})
}
```

I also have 'mouseout' action but it would be redundant to add it here, everything works just fine but I want all of the elements to be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentBlock` always refers to last `navtext`'s parent by the time loop is completed and event handlers are attached. Event handling takes place at later time.

Use `this` current element context in the event handler to get the reference of `parentElement` to do the desired operation.

```js
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('navtext')
for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
  texts[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(46,46,46,0.5)'
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="navblock"><a href="#">カ</a></div>
<div class="navblock" id="animeblock"><a class="navtext" href="#">ANIME</a></div>
<div class="navblock" id="signinblock"><a class="navtext" href="#">Sign In</a></div>
```